# json.loads() giving "ValueError: Expecting property name:"

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to convert sttr data type to dict in python using json.loads() function.
But I'm getting the error as:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/l`enter code here`ocal/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: Apparently your input isn't JSON.

Comment: (If you have unquoted keys, remember, that's not valid JSON.)

Comment: This is my input.
[{'entity_class': 'Hardware Entities (AHV)', 'status': 'recommended', 'uuid': 'de74178a-cbc7-4c69-ae2f-9e7042bf8e98', '__zprotobuf__': 'eNolzD1LAzEYB/DFScHBRXAKoUMr5khiLi/dCgpdCg7qIiLPJU/KQS4nyeEL6ne3p+vv/3K8CGiUMBaY77xhymvHAGVkDg1XsosWnT1bcI42tqZlwbWOqWAis5oD08J3VinOOwMXp', 'version': '2.4-1542668003', 'dependencies': '[{"entity_class": "Dell Update Manager", "version": "1.8-0.112", "exact": "false", "entity_model": "PT Agent on AHV (el6)"}]', 'entity_uuid': '00e8f575-d959-4d7f-860a-61cb84400b7a', 'order': 4}]

Comment: Yeah, that's not JSON.

Comment: Why ?
What's the modifications i needed to do ??

Answer (score 0):

In comments you gave the following example of the text you are trying to load as JSON:

```
[
  {
    'entity_class': 'Hardware Entities (AHV)',
    'status': 'recommended',
    'uuid': 'de74178a-cbc7-4c69-ae2f-9e7042bf8e98', 
    'zprotobuf': 'eNolzD1LAzEYB/DFScHBRXAKoUMr5khiLi/dCgpdCg7qIiLPJU/KQS4nyeEL6ne3p+vv/3K8CGiUMBaY77xhymvHAGVkDg1XsosWnT1bcI42tqZlwbWOqWAis5oD08J3VinOOwMXp', 
    'version': '2.4-1542668003', 
    'dependencies': '[{"entity_class": "Dell Update Manager", "version": "1.8-0.112", "exact": "false", "entity_model": "PT Agent on AHV (el6)"}]', 
    'entity_uuid': '00e8f575-d959-4d7f-860a-61cb84400b7a', 
    'order': 4,
  }
]
```

JSON should use double quotes, not single quotes. The above looks like native python data struct syntax. Here is the above dumped from native python to JSON.

```
import json

native_python_data = [
  {
    'entity_class': 'Hardware Entities (AHV)',
    'status': 'recommended',
    'uuid': 'de74178a-cbc7-4c69-ae2f-9e7042bf8e98', 
    'zprotobuf': 'eNolzD1LAzEYB/DFScHBRXAKoUMr5khiLi/dCgpdCg7qIiLPJU/KQS4nyeEL6ne3p+vv/3K8CGiUMBaY77xhymvHAGVkDg1XsosWnT1bcI42tqZlwbWOqWAis5oD08J3VinOOwMXp', 
    'version': '2.4-1542668003', 
    'dependencies': [
        {
            "entity_class": "Dell Update Manager", 
            "version": "1.8-0.112", 
            "exact": "false", 
            "entity_model": "PT Agent on AHV (el6)"
        }
    ], 
    'entity_uuid': '00e8f575-d959-4d7f-860a-61cb84400b7a', 
    'order': 4,
  }
]

json_string_with_escaping = json.dumps(js, indent=4)
print json_string_with_escaping
```

Comment: Actually this data is generated in my log file, so I can't change how the format is.

Comment: BTW, what is "js" you mentioned the last but one line ins json.dumps(js, indent=4)
It probable would be "native_python_data"

Comment: I tried doing the way you suggested above, It's coming as "str" data type. I want to extract few of the data associated inside it after doing json.dumps, so how can I do that.

ex: "entity_class": "Dell Update Manager",  I have to extract the value associated with entity_class here whose value will be changing inside the logs.

Comment: If I try json.loads(), it's converting as unicode data type.
If it is a dict data type I can try extracting the values using the keys of dict.